# Php ajax sort data based on user selected input

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a html form in which user can select an option upon which ajax call should be fired to php controller.

```
<form action="<?php echo URL . 'task/show_list/' . $this->tasks[0]->list_id;?>" method="GET" id="#sortTaks">
            <select name="sort_task" id="selectSortTask">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Sort by:</option>
                <option value="byName">Name</option>
                <option value="byDeadline">Deadline</option>
                <option value="byPriority">Priority</option>
                <option value="byStatus">Status</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, i would like that sort functionality provided asynchronously with ajax. This is the corresponding php code:

```
//controller

public function show_list($list_id)
    {
        if (isset($list_id)) {

            $task_model = $this->loadModel('TaskModel');
            $check      = $task_model->checkUserPermission($list_id);

            if ($check) {
                $tasks             = $task_model->showTasks($list_id);
                $this->view->tasks = $tasks;
                $this->view->render('task/task');
            } else {

                header('location:' . URL . 'dashboard/index');
            }
        } else {
            header('location:' . URL . 'dashboard/index');
        }
    }


//model

    public function showTasks($list_id)
    {

            if (isset($_GET['sort_task']) and !empty($_GET['sort_task'])) {
                $sort_parameter = strip_tags($_GET['sort_task']);
                $sort_order     = $this->sortData($sort_parameter);
                $sort_order     = 't.task' . $sort_order;
            } else {
                $sort_order = 't.task_name';
            }

            $sql = "SELECT t.task_name, t.task_id, t.task_priority, t.task_deadline, t.task_completed, l.list_id
                    FROM task AS t
                    LEFT JOIN list AS l ON l.list_id = :list_id AND l.list_id = t.list_id
                    WHERE l.user_id = :user_id
                    ORDER BY $sort_order";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array(':list_id' => $list_id, ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));

            return $query->fetchAll();

    }
```

//view snippet

```
            echo '<td>' . $value->task_name . '</td><td>' . $priority . '</td><td>';
            echo $task_deadline->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $overdue_until->format('%R %a day/s, %h hours, %i minutes');
            echo '</td><td>' . $status . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . URL . 'task/edit_task/' . $value->list_id . '/' . $value->task_id . '">Edit</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . URL . 'task/delete_task/' . $value->list_id . '/' . $value->task_id . '">Delete</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . URL . 'task/completed/' . $value->list_id . '/' . $value->task_id . '">Completed</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
```

What is the best approach in solving this problem? I'm a little bit confused with how should ajax call look like regarding mvc structure and presenting sorted data back to user.

Any help is much appreciated.

For now i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#selectSortTask').change(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var sortParam = $('#selectSortTask').val();

         $.ajax({
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             type: "GET",
             data: {sort_task: sortParam},
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
                alert(data);
             },
             error: function(error){
                alert(error);
             }
        });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Which alerts object Object as error. How to modify this ajax call and model/view/controller to get desired result? Alerts are for debugging purposes.

Comment: Do you want to return just the data? Or do you plan to return html? Your best bet is to use jQuery for the ajax and dom manipulation, and send the php view as json data.

Comment: I want to refresh the view that represents list of data(in my case tasks) based on user input in select field. Let's say user selects byName i want that list sorted byName and retured back to that view.

Comment: You could do the ajax call for just updated html and replace the table/list with what PHP generates or you could call for the data and have jquery replace the list items or rows in the html. You would make the initial ajax call the same way, passing the option value as a url param then you just have to deal with the response.

Comment: <?php echo URL . 'task/show_list/' . $this->tasks[0]->list_id;?>" method="GET" id="#sortTaks"> this part confuses me the most. How to get this url in ajax call?

Comment: Also there is a hash in your id for the form and maybe it was a bad copy/paste but your view is missing the opening tr. When i get to my laptop i will paste some code for the answer.

Comment: You can just hijack that form's submit event then send your ajax call to the action attribute of the form.

Comment: It's a typo. I will correct it. Thank you very much, it will be of great help.